# Avaliar ordem crescente com estrutura de repetição

Tags: c

> Escreva um programa para determinar se uma sequência de n números
>   digitados pelo usuário está em ordem crescente ou não. O usuário deve
>   fornecer quantos números serão digitados, ou seja, o valor de n.

**Estou com dificuldade nesse código, não consegui compreender bem como montar ele, eu fiz um pelo que entendi, mas não consegui desenvolver,** se alguém tiver dica para editar ele, ou mostrar como posso fazer, comenta ai, obrigado desde já...

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int Vezes_Digitada, Digitada; /*Vezes que o usuario ia digitar, e quantas vezes ele digitou*/
    float num; /*Numero que usuario ia digitar pra avaliação*/

    printf("Quantos numeros voce ira digitar?");
    scanf("%d", &Vezes_Digitada);
    while(Digitada <= Vezes_Digitada) /*aqui eu queria que saisse do while quando as vezes
    que você digitou chegasse ao numero de vezes que o usuario predefiniu, ex: digitou 15, 
    e ia aparecer pra vc digitar ate atingir o limite de 15 vezes digitadas*/
    {
        printf("%d Digite o numero:");
        scanf("%f", &num);
    }
    if(num > num)
    {
        /*Eu sei que ta errado, mas a intenção era avaliar se os numeros
        esta em ordem crescente ou não, mas nao sei como fazer isso*/
        printf("Ordem crescente");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Numeros digitados nao estao em ordem crescente");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparar se o numero é maior que ele próprio não tem sentido:

```
if(num > num)
```

Pois um número nunca será maior que ele próprio. Você quer na verdade comparar com o número anterior, que faltou criar uma variável para esse. Faltou também aumentar a variável `Digitada` dentro do `while`.

Tentado aproveitar o máximo da sua lógica, e mantendo o estilo poderia fazer assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int Vezes_Digitada, Digitada = 0; //Digitada - faltava o começar em 0
    float num, ultimo_num; //ultimo_num faltava

    printf("Quantos numeros voce ira digitar?");
    scanf("%d", &Vezes_Digitada);

    int crescente = 1; //a variável para saber se é crescente

    while(Digitada < Vezes_Digitada)
    //--------------^ sem o igual que estava aqui
    {
        printf("Digite o numero:"); //tinha um %d aqui a mais
        scanf("%f", &num);

        //Se não é o primeiro e o ultimo é maior que o atual
        //então não é uma sequência crescente
        if (Digitada != 0 && ultimo_num >= num)
        {
            crescente = 0; 
        }

        ultimo_num = num; //atualiza o ultimo
        Digitada++; //e os digitados
    }


    //no fim mostra se é crescente com base na variável atualizada no laço/ciclo
    if(crescente == 1) 
    {
        printf("Ordem crescente");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Numeros digitados nao estao em ordem crescente");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Veja este exemplo a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/YsZjc4)

A variável `crescente` foi definida como `int` no entanto o tipo ideal seria booleano, que é um tipo que não existe em C. A menos que precise especificamente de valores decimais do usuário seria mais aconselhado declarar `num` como `int`. E o `while` que tem seria mais simples de escrever com um `for`.

Logo uma solução melhor seria:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i, n , num, ultimo_num, crescente = 1;

    printf("Quantos numeros voce ira digitar?");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        printf("Digite o numero:");
        scanf("%d", &num);

        if (i != 0 && ultimo_num >= num){
            crescente = 0;
        }
        ultimo_num = num;
    }

    if(crescente == 1) {
        printf("Ordem crescente");
    }
    else {
        printf("Numeros digitados nao estao em ordem crescente");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Veja esta ultima solução também no Ideone](https://ideone.com/DULI9X)

Alternativamente poderá também colocar um `break` dentro do `if` que está no `for`/`while` para parar a inserção de números assim que um faça uma ordem não crescente.

Comment: se eu digitar 1 1 1 1 1 , da ordem crescente, tem alguma forma de arrumar isso? e muito obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: @WeslleyAF Sim faltou o `=` no `if` para ficar `>=` e não  `>`. Foi pura distração, mas vou já editar

Comment: Obrigado, mas em qual if?

Comment: @WeslleyAF No que está dentro do `while`/`for`. Já editei na resposta

Comment: ahh entendi, obrigado novamente

Comment: @WeslleyAF Sem problema, estamos cá para ajudar.

Comment: Sabe alguma maneira de fixar mais essa parte de repetição? estou tendo muita dificuldades com isso :/

Comment: @WeslleyAF Fixar ? como assim ?

Comment: fixar, melhorar, aprender, desenvolver... etc

Comment: @WeslleyAF O melhor é o mesmo que para tudo, estudar a teoria, seja por livros, videos, aulas, etc... E praticar! Praticar bastante, pois sem prática não há como.

Comment: Pois valeu, e boa noite :)

Comment: porque o int crescente=1 ficou depois do scanf? tem algum motivo em especial, ou poderia colocar essa variável junto no outro int?

Comment: @WeslleyAF O `crescente` já começou com `1` na sua declaração. A ideia é que estamos por defeito a assumir que os numeros são crescentes e atualizamos para `0` caso vejamos que algum já não é.